# .NET webpage/service/app communication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Alright guys, I'm in a little over my head on this one and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction, as I'm not really sure how to implement this.

I've got a piece of hardware that exposes a c#.net API.  Great.  Works wonderfully.  I want to collect data from this hardware using the API (so, a small c# app that does what I need) and then display the results on a web page.  Currently, I have the c# app grab data I care about and stick it in an RRD file, then I have the web page load the relevant data and display it to the user.

My question, then, is what do I do when I want to expose some of the API functionality to the user?  How do I go about making the 2 projects talk using .NET?

Some clarification:  The reason there are two parts is due to modularity.  The attached hardware and API can change, but as far as any client request is concerned, nothing's different, everything's just a web request to them.

Very little experience in big .net projects, so if you've got a better idea, let me know.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking - but the second app is just a Web App that's a collection of .aspx pages and some c# code-behind... which is all only run when a user requests that page.  I need my first app to be running constantly; is there a way to do that by integrating it with the code-behind somehow?

Comment: I just reread a couple times. Is that piece of hardware exposed to your web server? If so why not just write the web app?

Comment: If you have to make the data itself publicly available to other devs outside of your enviroment or if it absolutely has to be some kind of thin client that connects instead of just managing it on a single web server then I would consider WCF

Comment: Oh and for the most part ASP.NET exposes the same functionality as other C# applications. The web is simply another platform.

Comment: Additionally is there a reason your app needs to run constly?

Comment: The (first) app runs constantly to retrieve data points to store so I can go back and display historical conditions.

Yes, the hardware is exposed to the webserver, but how do I get a webapp that has a portion that's running constantly?

Comment: K got it. Then depending on how often the data needs to be updated? Is it an absolute requirement to be in realtime? all the time? I know I'm asking a lot of questions here but, if we are talking changes in terms of like once an hour then I think you could do fine with just a web app that queries using the api for current results and provides basic CRUD operations.

Comment: I can think of very few things that actually require up to the minute changes and all of them generally require specialized solutions. I.E. Air trafic controller, hospital life support monitor, Stock tracking software etc.....

Comment: The current implementation (where they are 2 standalone apps) has the c# program that uses the API updating the database file every 5 seconds.  This gives the web-app side the ability to answer a client request with data close enough to real-time data for this situation.
Are you saying I should just use the API from within the web app, and only perform querying when a page gets requested?

Comment: Well I was hoping that would be a possibility but, since that isn't but, that is something I definitely have to research... but to start with there is a similar question in this vein here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347771/how-to-implement-real-time-updates-in-asp-net and I was skimming through this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/09/10/building-real-time-web-application.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left it here for a few days to see if anyone else had any ideas.  I ended up scrapping the whole idea and consolidating everything into the web app.  Not my initial preference, but it works okay.  Thanks to Terrance for the brainstorming session under my question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be to use something like NServiceBus to post a message to the other component which communicates with the hardware. The hardware piece would pick up the message from the bus, process it and put the response back on the bus.

It's not a perfect solution, but I think it's definitely workable.

You should be able to find everything for it [here](http://www.nservicebus.com).

Comment: Eugh. I feel like there should be a solution other than wrapping it in yet another framework...

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Create a class library for the device handler. Add a `public class` which exposes a nice interface for the web app. Add a reference to the class library. Create your class and use it.